# Invalid syntax error when setting root = to in PyTorch

Tags: python, syntax-error, pytorch

```
import torchvision
from torchvision import transforms
train_data_path="./train/"
transforms = transforms.Compose([
transforms.Resize(64),
transforms.ToTensor(),
transforms.Normalize(mean=[0.485, 0.456, 0.406],
std=[0.229, 0.224, 0.225] )
])
train_data = torchvision.datasets.ImageFolder
(root=train_data_path,transform=transforms)
```

This is the error message:

```
File "<ipython-input-4-e470172b3902>", line 8
    (root=train_data_path,transform=transforms)
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

How would I be able to fix this?

Comment: Remove the newline. It should look like `train_data = torchvision.dataset.ImageFolder(root=... )`.  If you want the parameters on the next line you need at least the opening parenthesis after `ImageFolder`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the opening parentheses to be directly connected to the function, without any whitespace separating them. Try replacing the final two lines with:

```py
train_data = torchvision.datasets.ImageFolder(
    root=train_data_path, transform=transforms
)
```